# Overflowing my div's text to the left while preserving special characters

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

[I have this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9Lw9g2b9/) with this HTML markup:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-warning progress-bar-striped" style="width:90%;">
        <div class="first-bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width:10%;">
        <div class="second-bar">99.9% done, but I want this percentage to be on the left while maintaining this leftward overflow of text!</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the CSS:

```
@import url('//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css');
.first-bar {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
}
.second-bar {
    margin-top: 2px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
    direction: rtl;
}
```

My issue is that numbers aren't being aligned properly because of `direction: rtl` on my CSS. Instead of my div's text reading `99.9% done, but I want this percentage to be on the left while maintaining this leftward overflow of text!`, it reads `!done, but I want this percentage to be on the left while maintaining this leftward overflow of text 99.9%` How can I maintain this leftward overflow while preserving word order for some of these characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had to add `float: right;` instead of `direction: rtl;` on `second-bar`.